# php POST data to datetime

Tags: php, datetime, closures

I have an issue with my project. I want to create a `.ics` file with start and endtime defined by the user of the website. So I get a string for the start and the end year and for the start/end time as well. Now I want to create a `DateTime` object from this data. My problem is that I just get the timestamp from right now and not from the string made:

```
$eventStartDay    = $_POST["eventStartDay"];
$eventStartMonth  = $_POST["eventStartMonth"];
$eventStartYear   = $_POST["eventStartYear"];
$eventStartHour   = $_POST["eventStartHour"];
$eventStartMinute = $_POST["eventStartMinute"];
$eventStartSecond = $_POST["eventStartSecond"];
$startDateTime    = $eventStartYear . "-" . $eventStartMonth . "-" 
                  . $eventStartDay . "T" . $eventStartHour . ":" 
                  . $eventStartMinute . ":" . $eventStartSecond . "+01:00";

$eventEndDay    = $_POST["eventEndDay"];
$eventEndMonth  = $_POST["eventEndMonth"];
$eventEndYear   = $_POST["eventEndYear"];
$eventEndHour   = $_POST["eventEndHour"];
$eventEndMinute = $_POST["eventEndMinute"];
$eventEndSecond = $_POST["eventStartSecond"];
$endDateTime    = $eventEndYear . "-" . $eventEndMonth . "-" 
                . $eventEndDay . "T" . $eventEndHour . ":" 
                . $eventEndMinute . ":" . $eventEndSecond . "+01:00";

$cal = new SimpleICS();
$cal->addEvent(function($e) {
  $e->startDate = new DateTime($startDateTime);
  $e->endDate   = new DateTime($endDateTime);
```

I checked the strings with var_dump() and I got the right answers. They should look like this: '2016-01-18T19:00:00+01:00'

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you elaborate what you're getting, and what you expect, and how they differ?

Comment: don't you think you are initializing it again?

Comment: @jbafford I am getting the current time returned and not the time the user entered. I want to create a timestamp for an .ics file. And the user should enter the time he wants.

Comment: then most likely `$e` doesn't contain your start/end times, and you end up passing null (or a boolean false) to `DateTime`, which treats is as "generate a 'now' time"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the [PHP manual on Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the use language construct.

So you need to close over the DateTime objects, e.g. you need to do

```
$cal->addEvent(function($e) use ($startDateTime, $endDateTime) {
  $e->startDate = new DateTime($startDateTime);
  $e->endDate   = new DateTime($endDateTime);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me with such a dump mistake.